# Как правильно: светло-светлая или светло светлая?

Tags: раздельно-дефис

Какой вариант и почему считается правильным:

(1) «*О, **светло-светлая** и украсно украшена, земля Русская*! [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по русскому искусству (2000)]

(2) «*О **светло светлая** и украсно украшена, земля Руськая*! [С. М. Голицын. Сказания о земле Московской (1968-1988)]

Существуют ли подобные индивидуально-авторские образования такой структуры с прилагательным ***светлый*** (или с другими словами)?

Спасибо.

Comment: Что это вообще значит? Какой-то плеоназм. Всё равно что "зелёно-зелёная".

Comment: А это значит, что когда – плеоназм, а когда и средство художественной выразительности. А трава зелено зеленая, а солнце ярко яркое, ну разве не красиво?  В XII веке люди хорошо чувствовали красоту речи, а вам вот плеоназм не по душе. :)

Comment: Это просто слова, но смысла первое не несёт (а он — главное в речи). Другое дело: *яркое-яркое*.

Comment: Смысл – в усилении и в воздействии на ваши эмоции, причем в обоих случаях (ярко яркое и яркое-яркое).  Любой повтор имеет определенный смысл. Но светло светлая – это еще и особая форма,  исключительно для  чувствительных к поэзии и языку людей.  Светлый-светлый, так говорят все, это уже заурядное выражение, стертая метафора. Вам такие нравятся? :)

Comment: Дело в том, что *светло светлый* = *по-светлому светлый*. Это как? Может быть *светлый не по-светлому*? Если так, то это уместно.

Comment: По-светлому светлый? Это в словаре написано или откуда вы взяли? И почему у  вас везде один смысл – на первом месте и на всех остальных. Как это называется – прагматичность, да?  Или как?  А стихи вы любите – там как раз эмоции важнее.

Comment: Ну такой смысл, первое слово определяет второе. Смысл на первом месте, потому что он определяет корректность. А иначе получается "нарушать закон во благо".

Answer (score 1):

Если применять современные правила, то такой усилительный повтор надо писать через дефис. Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §118. Следующие разряды слов пишутся через дефис.
>
> (...)
>
> 2. Сочетания-повторы экспрессивного (часто усилительного) характера, в которых одна из частей осложнена приставкой или суффиксом, а также сочетания элементов, варьирующихся по звуковому составу, напр.: *красавица-раскрасавица*, *умница-разумница*, *волк-волчище*, *терем-теремок*, *горе-гореваньице*, *день-деньской*, *мука-мученская*, *тьма-тьмущая*, (...)
>
> (...)

На мой взгляд, дефис тут призван укреплять связь между двумя словами, составляющими одно усиленное понятие.

Однако, с вашим примером всё не так однозначно.

Во-первых, цитата из произведения чуть ли не тысячелетней давности, написанного на совсем другом языке. Если уж мы используем современную типографию и современное написание, то тогда стоит уж всё переводить в современный русский стиль. Мы и так уже искажаем оригинал, например, постановкой восклицательного знака посередь предложения.

Во-вторых, если уж проводятся параллели в структуре фразы, то и написание стоит определять одним принципом в обеих частях: либо *светло светлая и украсно украшена*, либо *светло-светлая и украсно-украшена*. Думаю, что первый вариант куда ближе к оригиналу, когда подобных изысков как дефис, не существовало.

В-третьих, тут однородные полное отыменное прилагательное и краткое причастие. Если даже убрать повторы, то сочетание *светлая и украшена* звучит, для современного меня, косноязычно. Уж если браться править текст и вставлять дефисы, то стоит адаптировать его полностью под современные лекала, а иначе получается какой-то незаконченный перевод. Например, заменить полное прилагательное кратким, что уже звучит куда созвучнее: *светла и украшена*.

Так что, полагаю, что в данной фразе два правильных варианта.

С точки зрения древне-русского:

> освѣтлосвѣтлаѩиѹкрасноѹкрашенаꙁемлѧрꙋськаѩ(...)

С точки зрения современного русского:

> О светло-светла и украсно-украшена земля русская!

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы прочитали  вопрос невнимательно. Там два момента. Во-первых, меня интересует, существует ли академический (общепринятый) вариант этого текста или такого варианта нет (то есть лингвисты и литературоведы пишут как кому нравится). Это вопрос скорее касается литературы и истории переводов. Второй момент заключается в том, что мне нужно ВЗЯТЬ  из текста два разных оформления  (светло-светлая и светло светлая)  и оценить форму написания с точки зрения современной орфографии.

Comment: Один вариант вы называете усилительным (значит, очень светлая?), а другой вообще не допускаете,  а почему?  В конце концов, это же красочный эпитет, а у вас получился заурядный повтор с целью усиления.  Как-то по стилю он тогда не очень подходит или может быть,  имеет другое значение. И произношение у этих форм разное, какое вам ближе или какое более уместно здесь? Для этого я спрашиваю о возможности применения подобных форм в современной литературе (может быть, со стилизацией под старину или народно-поэтическую речь). Вот на эти вопросы я не получила ответ.

Comment: Просто не знаю, что с вами делать. За сведения о публикациях «Слова» большое спасибо, за это вам полагается «печенька». Вы кажетесь мне образованным и много знающим человеком, и это не может не вызывать интереса и уважения. Но вы не любите русскую литературу и русский язык, и они никогда не будут вам понятны, не откроют своих тайн.

Comment: «Светло светлая» – это удивительное, завораживающее сочетание, это истинная древняя поэзия, которая переводит наше сознание на другой уровень. Он все дальше от нас, все недоступнее для нашего суетливого мира,  уже мало восприимчивого к  подлинному поэтическому слову.  И хорошо, что я вижу этот вариант в академическом издании, сама бы я написала так:  «О, светло светлая и украсно украшенная, земля Русская!»  Хотелось бы, чтобы этот стиль сохранился в нашей речи   хотя бы в каком-то виде – в сказках, в народном фольклоре, в современных театральных постановках.

Comment: Добавлю еще информацию о разном прочтении  сочетаний при раздельном и дефисном написании, так как на это обычно мало обращается внимания. Дефисное чтение делается в одно слово с двумя ударениями, основным и вспомогательным, пауза фактически не обозначена. Такое чтение сюда совершенно не подходит, это именно усиление признака, отнюдь не красочный эпитет (например, небо светлое-свЕтлое). При раздельном прочтении мы имеем возможность сделать полноценное ударение на каждом слове, получается симметричная конструкция: О, свЕтло свЕтлая и укрАсно укрАшенная…»

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, но у меня не было задачи предлагать другой перевод "Слова" (его и без меня перевели знающие люди). Я же предложила использование такого  художественного изобразительного средства в отдельном  обращении, а не в тексте. К тому же в наше время краткие формы имеют преимущественно предикативное значение, а раньше они склонялись и были ближе к значению определительному. Но меня радует хотя бы то, что вы не настаиваете на дефисном написании сочетания.